# Getting the .class of a generic class

Tags: java, generics

Suppose you have a certain class `C`, which supports generics (so `C<X>` defines a type). I would like to do something like:

I'd like to obtain an instance of the `Class<C<X>>` class. I would say that this can be obtained through the following expression:

```
C<X>.class
```

But the compiler doesn't agree with me on that :P

Any hint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). The type parameters are not available at runtime - all the instances of `C<Whatever>` are actually instances of simply `C`. Therefore, you can only write a class literal like `C.class`.

However, if you subclass a generic class with defining a concrete type parameter, such as this:

```
class StringC extends C<String> {}
```

... it is actually possible to obtain the value of the type parameter (which is `String`) via reflection. See these blogs:

- http://gafter.blogspot.cz/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html
- http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860

Answer (score 7):

The closest you can get is

```
@SuppressWarning("unchecked")
Class<C<X>> cxClass = (Class<C<X>>) (Class) C.class
```

As generics are a compile time feature, this doesn't really do much as you can see.

Comment: or (to avoid raw types) `(Class<C<X>>) (Class<?>) C.class`